# How to use image and vibrate_timings with my fcm message

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I want my FCM notifications to include a custom image and a vibration pattern.

The AndroidNotification class that Firebase provides as an example has both of these variables, but I haven't seen any way to get it working.

I've tried adding both of these variables to my notification message through a c# class AndroidNotification which gets serialized to json.
This is the documentation that makes me think it should be possible
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages
I have watched multiple online videos and went through multiple forms, but have still been unable to set a custom vibration pattern or display image along with my app icon.

Lots of places suggest that I use a data only message so I can handle displaying the notification myself, but if that is the only way to do it way does the AndroidNotification documentation(linked above) show fields for both vibrate_timings and image?

Note :
I've been testing on Android Versions 4, 5, and 8. On 8 I set up a notification channel and everything works fine with that including the vibrations, but still no image.
The image is included locally in the my apk at the same path as my custom icon.
Also my apk is built with unity but I don't think that should effect things.

Here is the json payload I'm sending, I get my custom sound, custom icon, custom color etc just fine, it's only the image and vibrate_timings that don't seem to be working.

```
{
   "validate_only":false,
   "message":{
      "data":null,
      "android":{
         "collapse_key":"new_messages",
         "priority":1,
         "restricted_package_name":"",
         "data":{

         },
         "notification":{
            "title":"A spoon is ready!",
            "body":"Grab it before someone else!",
            "icon":"spoonsbuzz",
            "channel_id":"cow",
            "color":"#0000FF",
            "sound":"cow.wav",
            "vibrate_timings":[
               "0.0s",
               "0.2s",
               "0.1s",
               "0.2s",
               "0.1s",
               "1.5s"
            ],
            "visibility":2,
            "tag":"new_messages",
            "click_action":"",
            "body_loc_key":"",
            "body_loc_args":[

            ],
            "title_loc_key":"",
            "title_loc_args":[

            ],
            "image":"spoonsbuzzimage",
            "notification_priority":4
         }
      },
      "apns":null,
      "token":"Bot"
   }
}
```

I expected my devices to get a notification with the image I added to the payload as well as vibrate in the pattern I set using vibrate_timings. The notification does come in just fine and everything else works but neither the image or the custom vibrations are included.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time, but if someone has this problem, they should add the `default_vibrate_timings` property, like this:

```
{...
    default_vibrate_timings: false,
    vibrate_timings: [
                "0.0s",
                "0.2s",
                "0.1s",
                "0.2s"
     ],
...}
```

For reference: [Documentation Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidConfig)