# Android how to use vibration when app is closed or when phone is locked

Tags: android, kotlin, vibration, android-vibration

I'm developing an app that periodically sends a notification that makes the phone vibrate in a repeated pattern, however, it only works when the app is open and and the phone is unlocked.
Whenever I receive the notification when the app is closed or the phone is locked it only plays the regular notification vibration that lasts a second or two.

This is the code I'm using to make the phone virbate.

```
vibratorManager = context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
            val vibrator = vibratorManager?.defaultVibrator
            vibrator?.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(longArrayOf(0L, 300L, 500L, 300L), 1))
```

Is there any way to make it so the phone always vibrates, including when it is locked or with the app closed?

Comment: Have you seen: [How to use image and vibrate_timings with my fcm message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70700543/295004)

Comment: I'm not using FCM, currently I'm just running that code whenever I send the notification

Comment: So searching didn't bring up: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#setVibrationPattern(long[])